# How to read a directory whose name has characters like " / " in python?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython, special-characters

I'm working on OSX 10.5.8 that permits even "/" on filename characters.

I have a wx.TextCtrl containing a directory to read (directory of music artists), there are bands called like this

- //Tense//
- ///▲▲▲\\

so in the text field I write down a directory name, written like this

```
/Users/....../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music////▲▲▲\\\/Untitled/
```

of course I get an error while reading it, because the program doesn't recognize the name of the band and slashes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `os.listdir()` for a parent directory with such a subdirectory in it please? It'll show us what codepoint was used instead.

Comment: maybe `ls -b` is helpful to find out what character it is.

Comment: See [Mac OS X Lion: What are invalid characters for a file name?](http://superuser.com/q/326103); using `:` in a filename in the terminal can show as `/` in the Finder and iTunes, and vice-versa. Replace `/` with `:` and you are there.

Comment: this is the output =>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Documents/python/MusicOrganizer/libs/music.py", line 105, in handlerAnalyze
    aListSongs = self.hFileSystemOp.readDirectorySongs(self.sMusicSource)
  File "/Users/..../Documents/python/MusicOrganizer/libs/files.py", line 80, in readDirectorySongs
    aListFiles = os.listdir(sDirectory)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music////\xe2\x96\xb2\xe2\x96\xb2\xe2\x96\xb2\\\\\\/Untitled/'

Comment: @axel: That's not what I asked for; I wanted the `iTunes Music` directory listed. :-)

Comment: i tried `:Users:...:Music;iTunes:iTunes Music:///▲▲▲\\\:Untitled:` and `/Users/.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/:::▲▲▲\\\/Untitled/` but i face the same mistake.

Comment: sorry @MartijnPieters ... here is the result about those directories `[u':::\u25b2\u25b2\u25b2\\\\\\', u'::Tense::']` is that any help?

Comment: @axel: What do you see when you do `ls Music/iTunes/iTunes Music` in the Terminal? And no; it's not the directory separator you need to replace with `:`, but the `///` of the directory name.

Comment: :::▲▲▲\\\
::Tense::
this on the terminal

Comment: if i write them like this it works perfectly. now i have to think how to manage it, while i analyze the entire string. i cannot demand the user to write the directory name replacing slashes with double dots..

Comment: @axel: Absolutely; it proves that the `/` is being translated to `:`. The triangles are unicode character `\u25b2`. You should be able to use `os.listdir` on that directory with that specific Unicode value, or encode it to UTF-8 for a non-unicode bytestring. It also means that roberts answer below is correct.

Comment: Just call `filename.replace('/', ':')` every time you need to use the filename.

Comment: i can't do it, because i receive a directory path, the one above i wrote, so this `/Users/.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/:::▲▲▲\\\/Untitled/` and i cannot make the replace on the entire string, i am thinking how to manage it in a fast smart way.

Comment: @axel doesn't wx provide some sort of file dialog which you can present your users? would save you a lot of hassle, and your users a lot of typing ;)

Comment: Try http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/FileDialog.html. I'm guessing that will be less hassle all around.

Comment: There's also a wx.lib.filebrowsebutton widget - http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton.html

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `/` characters in the filenames (not the directory names) with `:`.

Comment: That's just what I found out too: [Mac OS X Lion: What are invalid characters for a file name?](http://superuser.com/q/326103)

Comment: In Finder and file dialogs, those `:` characters show up as slashes, really confusing :(

Comment: Confirmed it on OS X 10.7 and 10.8.

Comment: i even tried with a simpler name
`/Users/......./Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/::Tense::/Memory/` representing the directory called **//Tense//** but nothing to do. but i have osx 10.5.8

Comment: if possible, i would like to write on my textfield the real name of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using wxPython's built-in widgets, such as [wx.FileDialog](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/FileDialog.html) or [filebrowsebutton](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton.html)

Here's a simple example that allows you to select multiple files:

```
def onOpenFile(self, event):
    """
    Create and show the Open FileDialog
    """
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, 
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        paths = dlg.GetPaths()
        print "You chose the following file(s):"
        for path in paths:
            print path
    dlg.Destroy()
```

I would recommend downloading the wxPython demo to check out its example of this widget and the other one I mentioned.